# How to use Bootstrap 3 grid system with table component?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

I have started a migration to grid system using Bootstrap 3, but the examples in the documentation are all using DIVs:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I made a somewhat redundant code that mixes the DIV classes with TABLE tags/classes:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

The problem is that the layout dobles the borders and I think the should be a better way of doing that. Any recommendations on that?

An example code in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7g8nV/1/

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered"> 
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="field-label col-md-3 active">
      <label>Field 1:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
      Value 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="field-label col-md-3 active">
      <label>Field 2:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
      Value 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="field-label col-md-3 active">
      <label>Field 3:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
      Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to double the borders.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Remove the `row` class from your `<tr>` elements. That class makes a non-table-row element look like a table-row and adds some styles that break a standard `<tr>`. You can still use the  "col" classes like normal:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered"> 
  <tr>
    <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
      <label>Field 1:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
      Value 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
      <label>Field 2:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
      Value 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field-label col-xs-3 active">
      <label>Field 3:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
      Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so no class or "row" is required in a div wrapping the table? or essentially the table class is accomplishing the same thing as the row class does when used on divs? thanks! - @ssorallen

Comment: The [`col-xs-X` classes](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L903) set percentage widths, which work by default for `<td>` elements. You don't need to use the `row` class at all.

Comment: NB: It's better to set the width classes in `<th>` or `<colgroup>` rather than individual cells. And any form controls (inputs etc.) in the cell need to have the form-control class applied.