# Set "margin-bottom" to "0" for all elements on the last row (responsive layout)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a responsive template using Bootstrap. I have multiple items located in a row, so that depending on a resolution there can be different amount of items in one row and a different amount of rows accordingly.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="item"> ... </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="item"> ... </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="item"> ... </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="item"> ... </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div> <!-- / .row -->
```

Every item has a bottom margin, so that they don't stick together vertically:

```
.item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Is there any way to set the bottom margin to "0" for all the items of **the last row**? (taken that we don't know which items will be in that last row on different resolutions).

*PS: Don't get confused with the `.row` container. This doesn't mean that the divs inside are a single row. This is just a wrapper for the .col-* containers.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m668fska/

Comment: Are there multiple `item` classes per column? Why aren't you using a table?

Comment: I am using a standard Bootstrap grid, not sure if tables is a good idea for a responsive layout.

Comment: do you want to target the last div with class "item".

Comment: tables with [bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614171/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-grid-system-with-table-component)

Comment: No, I want to target the divs located in the last row.

Answer (score 3):

Add a negative margin-bottom to the row - that way all your items (including the last row) will push down, the row will pull it back.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries that [match bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html), so something like

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    div.row>div.col-xs-6.col-sm-4.col-md-3:nth-last-child(-n+4)>div.item{
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
}
```

Then ditto for the following, except using `nth-last-child(-n+3)` and `nth-last-child(-n+2)` instead:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: It's ```margin-bottom``` not ```bottom-margin``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom

Comment: If I understand it right, this will target the last div.col-xs-12... only. What I want is to target all the .col-xs-12.....divs that would go on the last row.

Comment: Misunderstood, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Still not a solution, because .col-* divs inside the row container can go in several rows depending on the sreen resolution, that's the problem.

Comment: Ahh, I get it, so you have 4 `div.col-*` divs for the widest screen size, then 3 and 2 for smaller ones. See my updated answer then.

Comment: The answer above will work OK with a give number of items. However, if that's a picture gallery, for example, I can't know the exact number of pictures I will have to show, so I will have to edit the code every time I add a picture, which is not OK =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76537/discussion-between-huey-and-deka87).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, since you are trying to replicate a table you just need to add a style to the row;

```
.row {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

then overwrite the final row of the table;

```
.table:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

each `.row`, except the last one, will have some margin and only at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no pure CSS solution …

… so here's my take on a JavaScript solution: compare each item's offset top with the last item's offset top and distribute classnames accordingly.

```
 // tries to adjust margin-bottom of last-row elements.
function manage_last_row_items(){

  $('.last_row_management').each(function(){
    var
      $context = $(this),
      item_selector = $context.data('item_selector'),
      $last_item = $context.find(item_selector +':last-of-type').addClass('last_row_item'),
      final_top = $last_item.offset()  ? $last_item.offset().top  : 0
    ;
    $context.find(item_selector)
      .not($last_item)
        .removeClass('last_row_item')
        .filter(function(){
          var
            o = $(this).offset(),
            decision = false
          ;
          if (o) {
            decision = o.top === final_top;
          }

          return decision;
        })
          .addClass('last_row_item')
    ;
  });  // end of ( each )
}



$(document).ready(function(){
  manage_last_row_items();
  $(window).resize(manage_last_row_items);
});
```

Assuming this DOM:

```
<ul class="last_row_management" data-item_selector="li">
…
</ul>

<form class="last_row_management" data-item_selector="fieldset">
…
</form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7q9dtpop/)

(At this point, one could actually also take care of the last-column items …) (¬_¬ )