# Bootstrap alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page I created its design using bootstrap, I have an issue along with some questions to ask, first of all, can we use form-group inside a div with class of row? Or should we just use form-group?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
    body{
padding: 30px;
}
 h4.sub-header{
 padding-left:10px;
}

img.logo{
 width: 275px; 
 height: 70px;
}

.main-paragraph{
 padding: 30px;
}

#container{
 padding: 30px;
}
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">


                <h1>  HR Vacation request</h1>
                <h4 class="sub-header">HR Department</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>


    <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="logo.png" class="logo" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <p class="main-paragraph">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>


        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Date and availability</h3>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                              <th>  <label for="txtTodaydate">Today's Date</label></th>
                                <th> <label for="txtDateavailable">Date available</label></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="txtTodaydate" class="form-control" />
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="txtDateavailable" class="form-control" />
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <h3>For each day, list the hours you are available to work</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="txtMonday" class="control-label">Monday</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="txtMonday" class="form-control" />
                                </td>                             
                                <td class="col-sm-4">
                                 <label for="txtTuesday" class="control-label">Tuesday</label>
                                 <input type="text" id="txtTuesday" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                                             
                                <td class="col-sm-4">
                                 <label for="txtWednesday" class="control-label">Wednesday</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtWednesday" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                             <td class="col-sm-4">
         <label for="txtFriday" class="control-label">Friday</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="txtFriday" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="col-sm-4">
         <label for="txtSaturday" class="control-label">Saturday</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="txtSaturday" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                             <td class="col-sm-4">
                                   <label for="txtSunday" class="control-label">Sunday</label>
                                   <input type="text" id="txtSunday" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="txtThursday" class="control-label">Thursday</label>
         <input type="text" id="txtThursday" class="form-control" />
        </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
   

    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
       
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="txtName" class="form-label">Name:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName"/>
      </div>
      
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="txtAddress" class="form-label">Address:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAddress"/>
      </div>
      
      
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="txtHomePhone" class="form-label">Home Phone:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtHomePhone"/>
   </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label for="txtPhone" class="form-label">Phone:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPhone"/>
      </div>
      </div>


        </form>
        
      
     
    </div><!-- container-->


    <footer class="container-fluid"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen in the posting, I have the last 2 fields smaller than the others, you can notice that from the borders, how can I fix it? What's wrong that am doing?

This is my first bootstrap design, so any comments or advices will be much appreciated to make my skills better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things stand out.

1. on your phone fields you are using `col-sm-6`  this requires a parent `<div>` with the row class.
2. if you want all the fields the same outside of the table you need to keep some kind of uniformity to your layout, another words if you will be using columns use it on all the fields with rows for each.

HTML:

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/k6Lvxa5e/3/)

```
<div class="formbox">
                <h4>Requester Information</h4>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RName">Requester Name:</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Requester Name: must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Please Enter the Requesters Name!" id="RName" name="RName" style="width:400px" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RAddress">Property Address:</label>

                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Property Address: must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Please Enter the Requesters Address!" id="RAddress" name="RAddress" style="width:85%px" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RCity">City</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field City must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Please Enter the Requesters City!" id="RCity" name="RCity" style="width:300px" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RCity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RCounty">County:</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field County: must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Please Enter the Requesters County!" id="RCounty" name="RCounty" style="width:300px" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RCounty" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="RState">State:</label>

                            <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The State: field is required." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control  }" id="RState" name="RState"><option selected="selected" value="0">AL</option>
<option value="1">AK</option>
<option value="2">AZ</option>
<option value="3">AR</option>
<option value="4">CA</option>
<option value="5">CO</option>
<option value="6">CT</option>
<option value="7">DE</option>
<option value="8">FL</option>
<option value="9">GA</option>
<option value="10">HI</option>
<option value="11">ID</option>
<option value="12">IL</option>
<option value="13">IN</option>
<option value="14">IA</option>
<option value="15">KS</option>
<option value="16">KY</option>
<option value="17">LA</option>
<option value="18">ME</option>
<option value="19">MD</option>
<option value="20">MA</option>
<option value="21">MI</option>
<option value="22">MN</option>
<option value="23">MS</option>
<option value="24">MO</option>
<option value="25">MT</option>
<option value="26">NE</option>
<option value="27">NV</option>
<option value="28">NH</option>
<option value="29">NJ</option>
<option value="30">NM</option>
<option value="31">NY</option>
<option value="32">NC</option>
<option value="33">ND</option>
<option value="34">OH</option>
<option value="35">OK</option>
<option value="36">OR</option>
<option value="37">PA</option>
<option value="38">RI</option>
<option value="39">SC</option>
<option value="40">SD</option>
<option value="41">TN</option>
<option value="42">TX</option>
<option value="43">UT</option>
<option value="44">VT</option>
<option value="45">VA</option>
<option value="46">WA</option>
<option value="47">WV</option>
<option value="48">WI</option>
<option value="49">WY</option>
</select>
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RState" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RPostal">Zip:</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Zip: must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Please Enter the Requesters Postal code!" id="RPostal" name="RPostal" style="width:100px" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RPostal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RPhone">Requester Phone Number</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Requester Phone Number must be a string with a maximum length of 32." data-val-length-max="32" data-val-regex="Invalid Phone Number!" data-val-regex-pattern="^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$" data-val-required="You have not entered a phone numer for the Requester, Please enter the Requesters phone number so we can get back to you!" id="RPhone" name="RPhone" style="width:400px" type="tel" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div><div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8" for="RUserEmailAddress">Requester Email Address</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Requester Email Address must be a string with a maximum length of 128." data-val-length-max="128" data-val-regex="The Requester Email field is not valid, Please enter a valid email address!" data-val-regex-pattern="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" data-val-required="You have not entered an Email address, Please enter the Requesters email address!" id="RUserEmailAddress" name="RUserEmailAddress" style="width:400px" type="email" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RUserEmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks answer accepted. So I need to have row even if am using form-group? 

For your second point, what do you mean by: "the same outside of the table" ? I didn't really get your second point, can you match it with examples of what am doing? thanks

Comment: Anytime you use a column you need to have a parent div with a class of row. all the fields you are not placing in the tables you want to try and keep the same format if you want uniformity on your form. frankly im not a fan of tables with forms as when the viewport size changes they get messed up. i will show an example.

Comment: But how do I make a form that includes a table with borders? Do I use only divs and add borders in CSS? Can you show me some examples online? I have checked on bootstrap website and they're using tables, but it's not as I really want

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ is a good link to get you started.  an example of using tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614171/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-grid-system-with-table-component

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rich. One more question, which one do I put first? div with class row or div with class form-group? Which one is the parent to use in my forms?