# Tables to Bootstrap Grid in CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to transform a table into a Bootstrap grid, without using CSS. I can't use jquery to rewrite the tags, because the table has another JavaScript attached with events etc.

I want to accomplish that the cell are stacked on xs-devices.

From:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell11</td>
            <td>cell12</td>
            <td>cell13 Lorem ipsum ... magna aliquyam</td>
            <td>cell14 Li Europan ... li existent Europan</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

To:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 table-bordered gridtable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">cell11</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">cell12</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">cell13 Lorem ipsum ... magna aliquyam</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">cell14 Li Europan ... existent Europan</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

[image]

I created a small demo http://www.bootply.com/sRZF3LfHPU

- The upper part is the kind of table I get.
- The lower part is the kind of look I want to archive. Reduce the width to xs-device level to see the difference.

This is not a duplicate to [How to use Bootstrap 3 grid system with table component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614171/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-grid-system-with-table-component) because in that answer the cells will no stack.

Comment: Your demo link gives a 404 error. Can you post some code here? That's the preferred method.

Comment: @terrymorse Sorry, Bootply has problems. Added snippets to question.

Comment: Seems like some simple javascript to traverse your table elements and create the bootstrap-equivalent elements will do the trick. Where's the hiccup?

Comment: @terrymorse We are using a server framework + client js framework that is creating the table and I can't influence the code generation much. If I alter the tags, the table attached events, logic etc. don't work any more.

Comment: I can't think of a way to generate your bootstrap elements without modifying the DOM, sorry. AFAIK, table cells will never stack. You have to use divs.